# Why does `name` variable not make an error?

Tags: javascript, html

While I try to create and access property of an object in js,it make me confuse between undefined variables: `name` and `name_aaa`. Please refer to below code for more information:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Display the result here.</p>

<script>
    var persion = {
        name: "GSP",
        age: 50,
        show: function() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + this.name;
            /*
                Output: Hello GSP
            */
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + name;
            /*
                Output: Hello 
                It does not show any error.
            */
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + name_aaa; 
            /*
                sss.html:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: name_aaa is not defined
                at Object.show (sss.html:21)
                at sss.html:29
            */
        }
    };
    persion.show();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Could you please help explain why `name` is not error but `name_aaa` will throw error?

Comment: `name` is the global `window.name`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: @Xufox why it does not show anything after "Hello "?

Comment: @GSP Because `window.name` is the empty string by default. Just use the [browser console (dev tools)](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). You can answer these types of questions on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.